# Python for Apache: Sometimes Python error, sometimes file not found. Depends on content file

Tags: python, apache

I've mod_python running on Apapche 2 server.

When hello.py contains:

```
test
```

Python gives an error:

> NameError: name 'test' is not defined

When I replace content above with

```
from mod_python import apache

def handler(req):
    req.content_type = 'text/plain'
    req.write("Hello World!")
    return apache.OK
```

I get an 404 - file not found error.

Why is this and how can I get a python script running?

Comment: Why don't you read a tutorial on the software you are trying to use?

Comment: How have you integrated Python with Apache? mod_wsgi? mod_python?

Comment: @Marcin I did. Several tutorials

Comment: Do not use mod_python, mod_python has some bugs, and i was threw it into the unproductive trash try mod_wsgi

Comment: Please update your question with Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is obvious: there's no variable named "test"... (incidentally, this "silly" error was good for something... see below)

For the second (I'm assuming you're using mod_python), have you tried sending the HTTP header before writing any content?

```
req.send_http_header()
```

Also check if your URL is pointing to the right file, that might be the reason for the 404 error (Apache is finding your file correctly, or you wouldn't get the first error, so I'm assuming the script is fine and reachable, you just have to set the path correctly).